# Get the id of an input by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this part in my HTML code:

```
<div id="Container"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add input" class="btn-primary" id="AddInput"/>
```

and I have this script to add inputs in 'id=Container':

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var x = 0;
        //add inputs into container
        $("#AddInput").click(function () {
           $("#Container").append("<input id="myInput-${x}" data-x-degeri="${x}"/>");
           x++;
        });
        //show the value of x in this clicked x
        $(`[id^="myInput-"]`).on("change", function (e){
             var z = $(this).attr("data-x-degeri");
             alert(z);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This script should show me too the value of x of the input that I clicked. But it is not.
It's working when I am writing

```
<input id="myInput-${x}" data-x-degeri="${x}"/>
```

in my HTML directly .

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var x = 0;
            //add inputs into container
            $("#AddInput").click(function () {
               $("#Container").append(`<input id="myInput-${x}" data-x-degeri="${x}"/>`);
               x++;
            });
            //show the value of x in this clicked x
            $('[id^="myInput-"]').on("change", function (e){
                 var z = $(this).attr("data-x-degeri");
                 alert(z);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Add input" class="btn-primary" id="AddInput"/>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do string interpolation, but you will need backticks to get this to work: `\`<input id="myInput-${x}" data-x-degeri="${x}"/>\``

Comment: If you look in your web console, you'll find errors there which are important to pay attention to.

Comment: What is `myInput` in your code? What is `${x}` in your code?

Comment: @Richard yeah exactly thats what i am trying to do .

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the code is kind of complicated so i tried to make it easy with this way . sorry if its not understandable

Comment: Which doesn't in any way answer the questions.

Comment: Anyway i had an answer someone in the world understood it :D thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `id` and `data-x-degeri` value with single quote `'`.

```
$("#Container").append("<input id="myInput-${x}" data-x-degeri="${x}"/>");
                                  ^                            ^
```

Further, use event delegation to bind the `onchange` event to the new element.

```
$(document).on("change", `[id^="myInput-"]`, function (e){...}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = 0;
  //add inputs into container
  $("#AddInput").click(function() {
    $("#Container").append("<input id='myInput-${x}' data-x-degeri='${x}'/>");
    x++;
  });
  //show the value of x in this clicked x
  $(document).on("change", `[id^="myInput-"]`, function(e) {
    var z = $(this).attr("data-x-degeri");
    alert(z);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add input" class="btn-primary" id="AddInput" />
```